# connecting to a signal with qdbus

Tags: dbus, qdbus

`qdbus` is rather straightforward when calling methods, but is it possible to connect to a signal with it? Signature:

```
signal void org.kde.kwin.Scripting.printError(QString text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `#dbus` on `irc.freenode.org`:

```
thiago | the command-line utility can only send calls
thiago | use dbus-monitor for that
```

Comment: with gdbus is better I think, ex.: `gdbus monitor -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session` so you can monitor if screen got locked; linking: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505681/unity-how-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked